# React race condition causing undefined id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, race-condition

I am just trying to figure out a weird issue in my React project. So I am executing some code in my useEffect. As you can see, I am trying to grab the currentObj from an array of objects based on searchTerm. However, there seems to be a race condition
in getting the value searchTerm. The toggleFilter ans setAvailabilities functions below are throwing an error saying that the `id` is not defined. And the page crashes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const search = window.location.search;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
    let param = "";

    if (search.includes("neighborhood")) {
      param = params.get("neighborhood");
      const searchTerm = search.toLowerCase();
      if (searchTerm) {
        const currentObj = searchTerm && locations.find(item => item.linktitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
        console.log(searchTerm, currentObj);

      toggleFilter(currentObj.id);
      setAvailabilitiesFilter([currentObj.id]);
      }
      
    }


    return () => resetAllFilters();
  }, []);
```

However, if I hardcode a value into it, it actually renders ok.

```
const currentObj = searchTerm && locations.find(item => item.linktitle.toLowerCase().includes('manhattan'));
```

But of course, I don't want to hardcode the value as I expect to dynamically render the `searchTerm`

Is there any way I can in the useEffect wait until searchTerm is defined before running that .find method? I also tried adding the `searchTerm` in the dependency array but that doesn't seem right as it is not giving suggestions there and seems not to be scoped there.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using React Router you can try [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to replicate what you were doing to some extent in a code sandbox and the functionality seems to work. Originally, it worked fine until I passed a string which was not in the `locations` array and I got the same undefined error.

So basically, what you need to do is first run the `find` function. Then only, if there is a match, i.e. the `find` function does not return `undefined`, will the `togglefilters` and other code be run. You can see the code below.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const locations = [
  {
    id: 1,
    linktitle: "Paris",
    country: "France"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    linktitle: "Madrid",
    country: "Spain"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    linktitle: "Shanghai",
    country: "China"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    linktitle: "London",
    country: "England"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const toggleFilter = (id) => {
    console.log("toggled id:", id);
    setFilter(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const search = window.location.search;

    // this statement avoids any matches with empty strings

    if (search === "") return;

    const searchTerm = search.slice(1).toLowerCase();

    // first check whether a location is matched
    // before running any other functionality

    const location = locations.find((item) =>
      item.linktitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );

    if (location) {
      toggleFilter(location.id);
      console.log(searchTerm, location);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code sandbox link is here where you can see what is happening and view the console logs:

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sound-wyb0iz?file=/src/App.js:0-831

You can see the console logs of the objects appear if they are cities in the location array which have been queried in the query params. Also, there is no undefined with the IDs which are filtered.

I sliced the `searchTerm` so that the initial "?" would be removed from the string.